# Is there a way to read Excel file from Sharepoint using C# .net core 6.0

Tags: c#, .net-core, sharepoint

I have tried to load the Excel file using its link, which is stored in Sharepoint.
I want to load the file as a C# object.

I have tried a couple of approaches, but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: Are you using Interop or as an Oledb connection?  Are you using JET or ACE driver?  Can you open file locally?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is your problem solved? if you still need further assistance, please feel free to post back.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Microsoft Graph API approach. If you have not already tried it,here is the code snippet for accessing an Excel file stored in a SharePoint site using the Microsoft Graph API and MSAL for .NET:

```js
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph.Auth;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using System;

// Define the SharePoint site URL and Excel file path
string siteUrl = "https://yourtenant.sharepoint.com/sites/your-site";
string filePath = "/Shared Documents/YourExcelFile.xlsx";

// Define the client ID of your Azure AD application
string clientId = "your-client-id";

// Define the scopes for accessing Microsoft Graph
string[] scopes = { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

// Define the instance and tenant ID of your Azure AD tenant
string instance = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/";
string tenantId = "your-tenant-id";

// Create a new PublicClientApplication instance with MSAL
IPublicClientApplication publicClientApp = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
    .Create(clientId)
    .WithAuthority($"{instance}{tenantId}")
    .Build();

// Get an access token for Microsoft Graph using MSAL
AuthenticationResult authResult = await publicClientApp
    .AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes)
    .ExecuteAsync();

// Create a new GraphServiceClient instance with the access token
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(
    new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
        async (requestMessage) =>
        {
            requestMessage.Headers.Authorization =
                new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue(
                    "Bearer", authResult.AccessToken);
        }));

// Get the Excel file from SharePoint using Microsoft Graph
DriveItem excelFile = await graphClient
    .Sites[siteUrl]
    .Drive
    .Root
    .ItemWithPath(filePath)
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();

// Read the contents of the Excel file into a byte array
byte[] excelContents = await graphClient
    .Sites[siteUrl]
    .Drives[excelFile.ParentReference.DriveId]
    .Items[excelFile.Id]
    .Content
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();

// Process the Excel file contents as needed
// For example, you can use the OpenXml SDK to read the Excel file
// See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/ for more information
```

Answer (score 0):

If the question is to retrieve a file's contents from its full URL, the answer is by using the SharePoint Rest API or Microsoft Graph API. Once you're resolved the authentication method, you may use either endpoint to retrieve the file. As I am more familiar with the SharePoint API, here's the endpoint:

`https://<tenant-name>.sharepoint.com/sites/<site-name>/_api/web/getFileByServerRelativeUrl('<file-server-relative-url')/$value`